# Check currency field only contains 1 fullstop

Tags: regex

can someone please help me to compose a regular expression to check a currency  string is in a particular format - 300.00

It can have only numbers both before and after the '.'. However i want only one occurrance of the '.'.

Hence 300.00. or 300.0.0 is invalid.

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$
```

This means, beginning of string (`^`), one or more digits (`[0-9]+`), optional period (`\.?`), then 0 or more digits, then the end of the string.  You can modify it as needed, e.g. to allow strings beginning with period (change first + to `*`) or make the period mandatory (remove `?`).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to represent a string that is strictly correct for currency, then you'd most likely want something like `^\d+\.\d{2}$`, since you typically represent currency with 2 decimal points. If you're not picky, then `^\d+\.\d+$` will match any number of decimal places or `^\d+\.?\d*$` will match whole numbers as well as numbers with any number of decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

I think this'll do it:   `^\d+\.\d+$`

This will match a string that consists of one or more digits, exactly one '.', and one or more digits.

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex for matching -

```
^\d+\.\d+$
```

Answer (score 1):

per @mathew's answer you probably want to anchor your regex at the start and end of the string (so ^ and $ respectively). per @eldarerathis you probably want to limit the number of digits after the decimal point. You may also want to allow an optional $ sign in front; and you probably want to allow the user to drop the cent's component altogether. So:

```
^\$?\d+(\.\d\d)?$
```

Which is

```
^         start of string
\$?       optional dollar sign
\d+       at least 1 digit.
(\.\d\d)? optional decimal point followed by exactly two digits 
          (you could use \d{2} here as well)
$         end of string
```